# Can I run Demobench across different machines or only locally?

Tags: corda

Is there some straightforward way of running a CorDapp demo across different machines using the UI provided by the Demobench?

Or is the Demobench hardcoded to only run locally?

I'm particularly interested in the Node Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

The Demobench is mainly used as a way of quickly spinning up nodes, web servers and instances of the Node Explorer for demo purposes.

As such, part of its built-in process is to spin up and connect to nodes locally, not across machines. So yes, it is hardcoded to run locally.

However, the Node Explorer can be run across different machines and is available as a stand-alone tool.

You can download the latest version [here](http://www.corda.net/resources) and find instructions on running it [here](https://docs.corda.net/head/node-explorer.html)